# Android showing a loading view by using a separate xml file

Tags: android

I want to load another xml file but keeping the current xml transparent. The second layout is just a small loading image so in the backgroung i want to show the existing xml. How do i do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your loading image into a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout, and make the layout fill the whole window but with transparent background.